# Sudo android return "sudo: android: command not found"

Tags: bash, permissions

I use Ubuntu 15.04 - Gnome,

For any reason when I try to execute the function "Android" its return

```
bash: /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: Permission denied
```

and when I type sudo android the bash return

```
sudo: android: command not found
```

Any solution? This can affect to "Cordova"?

Thanks in advance.

---

Update:

`file /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android`

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux Hope 3.19.0-33-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:18:12 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

`stat /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android`

```
File: ‘/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android’
Size: 3498          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 786692      Links: 1
Access: (0744/-rwxr--r--)  Uid: (249512/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 5000/     UNKNOWN)
Access: 2015-11-10 15:01:53.838926405 +0200
Modify: 2015-10-14 10:44:06.000000000 +0300
Change: 2015-11-10 14:50:37.671590304 +0200
Birth: -
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `file /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android; stat /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android; uname -a, lsb_release -a`

Comment: I miss the output of `stat /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unknown group (gid 5000) and an unknown user (uid 249512) and ... I guess ... you are not the user with the uid 249512.

Set the permissions - everything in `/opt` should have the owner `root` and the group `root`:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /opt/android-sdk-linux
```

Set the executable rights:

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

Run the script with `sudo` rights (**a very bad idea**)

```
sudo /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

so better change the directory

```
cd /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools; sudo ./android
```

**If** `/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/` is in your PATH this will work too:

```
sudo android
```

**And once again: Using `sudo` to run this application is not necessary and a VERY bad idea!**

---

But I suspect that there are additional problems with other files in your `/opt/android-sdk-linux` installation.

Comment: Nice catch, Now  with command "android" just open the app,  but with "sudo android" still get "sudo: android: command not found"

Comment: Don't use `sudo` for that. But to explain the behavior: `sudo /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android` <- works `cd /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools; sudo ./android` <- works. `android` <- works **IF** `/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/` is in your path for the current user.

Comment: Why? Can you explain me please?

Comment: I should tell you the rights system of Linux? Sorry, no.

Comment: I know them, but whats the differences by execute with a full path or not?

Comment: You need the full path, if the path isn't in the environment variable PATH. You don't need the full path, if the path is in the environment variable PATH. Each user can have its own environment.